# How does On/Off Reversal work in Life-Like Cellular Automata

Tags: cellular-automata

I've recently been made aware of the concept of [on-off rule reversal](https://www.conwaylife.com/wiki/Black/white_reversal) in life-like cellular automata. I understand the algorithm for calculating the rule reversal from a given rule. But I don't understand *why* the algorithm is the way that it is, or how it was derived. I also can't seem to find any explanations anywhere.

Comment: So you're asking e.g. why the on/off reversal of the totalistic CA rule B3/S23 on the 8 neighbor 2D Moore lattice (a.k.a. Conway's Game of Life) is B0123478/S01234678? That question is really mainly about the [B/S rule notation](https://www.conwaylife.com/wiki/Rulestring#B.2FS_notation); if the rule were instead expressed as, say, a table of neighborhoods and next-generation states, on/off reversing it would be much simpler (just negate both the inputs and the outputs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transition rule of a Life-like cellular automaton (or, more generally, any two state outer-totalistic CA) can be regarded as a function $f$ that takes the current state $s$ of a cell (represented as $1$ = on and $0$ = off) and the number $n$ of cells in state $1$ its neighborhood and outputs the state $f(s, n)$ of the same cell (again, $1$ = on and $0$ = off) in the next generation.

For example, the transition rule of Conway's Game of Life (B3/S23) can be represented as the function
$$f(s, n) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $s = 0$ and $n = 3$,} \\
1 & \text{if $s = 1$ and $n \in \{2,3\}$,} \\
0 & \text{otherwise.} \\
\end{cases}$$

Given any such transition function $f$, we can define the transition function $f'$ of the corresponding state-reversed rule simply as $$f'(s, n) = 1 - f(1 - s, M - n),$$ where $M$ is the size of each cell's neighborhood (e.g. $M = 8$ for Life-like CA).

It should be easy to see that the function $f'$ is equivalent to $f$, except that we've simply swapped the state labels $0$ and $1$.

---

Conversely, given a transition function $f$, we can reconstruct the corresponding B/S rule string as follows:

- after "B", list all numbers $n \in \{0, \dots, M\}$ for which $f(0, n) = 1$; and
- after "S", list all numbers $n \in \{0, \dots, M\}$ for which $f(1, n) = 1$.

Now, applying the same construction to $f'$, we can see that:

- $f'(0, n) = 1$ if and only if $f(1, M-n) = 0$; and
- $f'(1, n) = 1$ if and only if $f(0, M-n) = 0$.

In other words, the rule string for the state-reversed rule represented by $f'$ will have:

- after "B", only those numbers $n$ for which $M-n$ does *not* appear after "S" in the original rule; and
- after "S", only those numbers $n$ for which $M-n$ does *not* appear after "B" in the original rule.